# Ruby or regex to strip excess line breaks

Tags: ruby, regex, line-breaks

How would you turn this:

```
Dear Fred



How are you?






Regards
John
```

Into this:

```
Dear Fred

How are you?

Regards
John
```

Note: Single and double breaks are allowed, but no more than that. For example, we want to go from:

```
"Dear Fred\n\n\n\nHow are you?\n\n\n\n\n\n\nRegards\nJohn"
```

to

```
"Dear Fred\n\nHow are you?\n\nRegards\nJohn"
```

But should also work for "\r\n".

Comment: For me the complications came when trying to deal with the various types of newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
s.gsub /(\r?\n){3,}/, '\1\1'
```

Seems to work with your example at least:

```
irb(main):060:0> s
=> "Dear Fred\n\n\n\nHow are you?\n\n\n\n\n\n\nRegards\nJohn"
irb(main):061:0> s.gsub /(\r?\n){3,}/, '\1\1'
=> "Dear Fred\n\nHow are you?\n\nRegards\nJohn"
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
(\r\n|\n|\r)\1+
```

with

```
\1
```

Where `\1` refers to a back-reference. In ruby they are done through `$1`, I believe.

Comment: Doesn't that result in only single breaks?

Comment: @Franky: Not when I tested it. Does it for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
str.gsub!(/\n{3,}/, "\n\n")
str.gsub!(/(\r\n){3,}/, "\r\n\r\n")
```

The regex /\n{3,}/ searches for 3 or more consecutive linebreaks (\n). These are substituted with 2 linebreaks.
Repeat for \r\n.

```
["\n", "\r\n"].each{|lb| str.gsub!( /(#{lb}){3,}/, lb*2 )}
```

Does the same.